# cannot display data based on passing parameter?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jquery-mobile

i have a difficulty to display data based on the parameter pass. below are my code based on the sequence. My problem is, when is debug, the controller where it pass to second page jsp, it retrieve the parameter which is courseId, but when it doesn't display the data in jsp and in the controller of get the data.. I know my question is long but please help me.the first page will show the list of courses available. when the user click on the course, it will go the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="MregisteredClassesDetail.phone")
public final ModelAndView registeredClassesDetail(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response,HttpSession session) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    log.debug("Registered Classes Detail:");
    log.debug("CourseId:"+request.getParameter("courseId"));
    request.setAttribute("page",  AlteraCommonConstant.DEFAULT_PAGE);
    request.setAttribute("row",  AlteraCommonConstant.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
    request.setAttribute("courseId","courseId");
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Registered Classes Detail");
    mav.setViewName("mobile/MregisteredClassesDetail.jsp");
    return mav;
}
```

then it will go to the jsp second page..

```
$('#MregisteredClassesDetails').live('pageshow', function(){
    var rowInput = "1";
    var pageInput = "1";
    var idInput = document.getElementById("courseId");

    $.ajax({
     url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getRegisteredClassesDetails.html',
     data: ( {rows : rowInput , page : pageInput, courseId : idInput}),
     type: 'POST',

     success: function(json_results){
       $('#list').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"</ul>');
       listItems = $('#list').find('ul');
       html  = '#################################################################################################';
       html += '<h1>' +json_results.courseName+'</h1>';
       html += '#################################################################################################';
       html += '<br> Registration #    : '+json_results.regNo+'</br>';
       html += '<br> Status            : '+json_results.regStatus+'</br>';
       html += '<br> Location          : '+json_results.courseLoc+'</br>';
       html += '<br> Start Date        : '+json_results.startDate+'</br>';
       html += '<br> Registered Person : '+json_results.fullName+'</br>';
       html += '<br> Rate              : '+json_results.rate+'</br>';
       listItems.append(html);

       $('#list ul').listview();
       $.mobile.pageLoading(true);      
    }
});
});
```

and the html

```
<form name="ViewClassForm" method="POST">
<input name="courseId" type="hidden" value="${MregisteredClassesDetail.courseId}"/>
</form>
<div data-role="page" id="MregisteredClassesDetails" data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b"><h1></h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="courseDetail"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="list"></ul>
    </div> 
</div><!-- /content -->
```

then it will go to the controller back to retrieve data..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getRegisteredClassesDetails.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody CustomPagedResultResponse getRegisteredClassesDetails(
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session) {
    CustomPagedResultResponse paging = new CustomPagedResultResponse();

    log.debug("getRegisteredClassesData.html:");  
    log.debug("rows:"+request.getParameter("rows"));
    log.debug("courseId:"+request.getParameter("courseId"));
    log.debug("page:"+request.getParameter("page"));
    log.debug("sidx:"+request.getParameter("sidx"));
    log.debug("sord:"+request.getParameter("sord"));

    String page = request.getParameter("page");
    int pageSize = new Integer(request.getParameter("rows")).intValue();
    StringBuffer condition = new StringBuffer();
    if (request.getParameter("sidx") != null && !request.getParameter("sidx").equals("")) {
        condition.append(request.getParameter("sidx"));
        condition.append(" ");
    }
    if (request.getParameter("sord") != null && !request.getParameter("sord").equals("")) {
        condition.append(request.getParameter("sord"));
    }
    log.debug("condition: " + condition.toString());
       log.debug("page:"+page);
       log.debug("row:"+pageSize);

    String courseType = "%";

    UserProfile userProfile = (UserProfile)session.getAttribute("userProfile");


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Retrieve  Total Record first
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    RegisteredClassesSearch search = new RegisteredClassesSearch();
    search.setLanguage("ENU");
    search.setLoginRowId(userProfile.getContactRowId());
    search.setRegNo(null);
    search.setAction("1");
    search.setCourseType(courseType);
    search.setPage(null);
    search.setPageSize(null);
    search.setOrderBy(null);

    Integer recordCount = registeredClassesService.getTotalAccounts(search);
    log.debug("*****Training Controller Total record:"+recordCount);
    System.out.println("*****Training Controller Total record:"+recordCount);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Retrieve  Total Record first
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(recordCount>0){

        System.out.println("******** Login Id:"+userProfile.getContactRowId());
        System.out.println("******** Course Type:"+courseType);
        System.out.println("******** Page Size:"+pageSize);
        System.out.println("******** Page:"+page);
        System.out.println("******** Order By:"+condition);

        List<RegisteredClassesTest> registeredClassesView = registeredClassesService.getAccounts(search);

        paging.setRows(registeredClassesView);
    }else{
        paging.setRows(null);
    }


    paging.setRecords(String.valueOf(recordCount));
    paging.setPage(page);
    int total = recordCount % pageSize == 0 ? recordCount / pageSize : recordCount / pageSize + 1;
    paging.setTotal(String.valueOf(total));

    return paging;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo here in this case.

In your first controller you are setting the course id in request parameter like below.

```
request.setAttribute("courseId","courseId");
```

According to me it should be

```
request.setAttribute("courseId",some int value);
```

You are not adding some actual value in **courseId**.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: does it mean i need to put the value there? the value i want to take from previous page

Comment: Yes. Obviously. If you don't pass it to jsp from anywhere then how can you get it in another page.

Comment: do i need request.setAttribute("courseId",some int value);? if i don't put this, the parameter doesn't send? is there other way to pass parameter?

Comment: yes through the map in model and view. You can set that in map and put that as a hidden field value in the jsp form and then get that value back when you submit the form.